# Doubt about the definition of "complete theory"

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus, first-order-logic, predicate-logic

I'm reading this book: [https://www.amazon.com/Introduction-Logic-Methodology-Deductive-Mathematics/dp/048628462X/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=tarski+alfred&qid=1581605512&sr=8-2](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/048628462X) and it states:

"A theory is called complete, if of any two contradictory sentences which are formulated by employing exclusively the terms of the theory under consideration (and of the theories preceding it), at least one sentence can be proved within this theory."

and then it says: "a discipline might be considered ideal, if it contains among its asserted statements **all true sentences** which are from the domain in question, and not a single false one. A deductive theory certainly falls short of our ideal unless it is both consistent and **complete**."

my question is, how can a theory have all true sentences and be complete? I don't know if I don't understand something in the definition, but saying "if of any two contradictory sentences ..., at least one can be proved" to me it seems that in this theory one of these sentences is false (since they are contradictory). Is it because it's an implication "if.. then.." and if the antecedent "of any two contradictory sentences" is false the implication is true? or what am I missing?

Comment: Not clear... See *completeness* (aka: [negation completeness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)#Syntactical_completeness)). We have that, for a sentence $\varphi$ in the language of e.g. first-order arithmetic, like $\forall x(x \ge 0)$, that either it is TRUE (in the intended model of the theory), or it is FALSE. In this second case, its negation $\lnot \varphi$ will be TRUE.

Comment: Sylly example: $\forall x(x \ge 0)$ is TRUE.  The sentence $\forall x(x > 0)$ is FALSE; thus, its negation:  $\exists  x \lnot (x > 0)$ IS TRUE.

Comment: I don't understand.. what is not clear? the question or the book? and does the author mean "syntactical completeness" when he talks about completeness?

Comment: I'm not sure what your confusion is. It seems like you're thinking that "proving all true sentences" is the same thing as "proving that all sentences are true," which are entirely different things.

Comment: Tarski is speaking of "deductive theory"; this means that he is speaking of **proving** in the theory (i.e. deducing from the axioms) **all TRUE sentences**. The issue is clearly that of G's Incompleteness Th: the well-known example of first-order Peano Arithmetic that, **if** consistent, is not **complete**.

Comment: In that context, G's Theorem shows how to manufacture a **sentence** $G$ in the language of the theory such that neither $G$ nor $\lnot G$ is provable. By the reasoning in my first comment above, obviously one of them must be TRUE in the intended model $\mathbb N$.

Comment: Tarski's def must be read: CONSISTENT= at most one is provable; COMPLETE= at least one is provable. The IDEAL is CONS+COMPL=exactly one is provable.

Answer (score 2):

The two contradicting sentences don't have to be part of the complete theory, they only have to be "formulated by employing exclusively the terms of the theory under consideration (and of the theories preceding it)".

Meaning:

Given a theory $K$, such that $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$ are all the terms of $K$ and of $K$'s preceding theories, and for any given $\varphi$ such that $\varphi$ is a sentence that is formulated from $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$, $K$ is said to be "complete" iff it proves $\varphi$ or $\neg \varphi$.

Neither $\varphi$ nor $\neg \varphi$ need to be part of $K$, the requirement is for them ($\varphi$ and $\neg \varphi$) to be formulated from $t_1,t_2,...,t_n$.